# Java Spring Data JPA - Many to Many

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to develop rest application, and key for it is a persistence layer. Now i have these 2 entities :

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="Usr")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="USER_ID")
private long id;

/******/
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="users",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Team> groups;
}
```

and 2nd Team,

```
Entity
@Data
@Table(name="TEAM")
public class Team {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="TEAM_ID")
private long id;
/*************/
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="USER_IN_GROUP", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TEAM_ID",referencedColumnName = "TEAM_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")})
private List<User> users;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="container",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Item> items;
}
```

Following method is placed in UserController

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public void addUser(@RequestBody User user){
    Team team = new Team();
    team.setCreationDate(new Date());
    team.setItems(new ArrayList<Item>());
    team.setName(user.getName()+" "+user.getSurname());
    user.setJoinDate(new Date());
    user.setLastLoginDate(new Date());
    user.setGroups(Arrays.asList(team));
    repository.save(user);
}
```

My issue is that after sending JSON with user object, it creates java User object and persist it in database with no problem. But Team is created with id which equals user_id+1, and association with those two entities remains empty.

and this is application.properties of springboot :

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pricetracer
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Comment: You set user.groups, which is the inverse side of the association, but you fail to set team.users, which is the owner side.

Comment: I switched this, and now after creating new user, when i want to receive an user by id (or allUsers), it returns infinitive list of users http://i.imgur.com/V7WIRpn.png. And application freezes, i think that it stucks in infinitive loop.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the way you save the user. It's just that you ask Jackson to serialize a user, so it serializes the user. Since the user has teams, it serializes the teams. Since the teams have users, it serializes the users, etc. etc. Don't serialize your entities, but serialize DTOs instead, or add `@JsonIgnore` to at least one side of the association to break the cycle.

Comment: Thank you very much, It helped indeed :)